# Columns and Rows are backwards JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-table

I have the following code in index.html which grabs a dictionary list and
prints out keys and values into a table

```
$(function() {
      $('a#search').bind('click', function() {
        $.getJSON('/_search', {
          a: $('input[name="a"]').val()
        }, function(data) {
          var tableData = '<table>'
          $.each(data.result, function(key, value){
            tableData += '<tr>' + '   ' + key + '   ' + '</tr>';
            alert(key)
            $.each(value, function(val){
                alert(value[val])
                tableData += '<td>' + value[val] + '</td>';
              });
          });
          tableData += '</table>';
          $('#table').html(tableData);
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
```

However my output is as follows

```
Developer Publisher ReleaseDate Title
Office    Koukan    Jorudan Beam Software
Shouei    VAP       Hi Tech Expressions
March 18, 1994  November 18, 1994   October 1, 1993
Idea no Hi  Pachinko Hi Hisshouhou  hunThe Hunt for Red October
```

When the output should be

```
   Developer      Publisher ReleaseDate Title
   Office Kouan   Shouei    ...         ...
   Jorudan        VAP       ...         ...
   Beam Software  ...       ...         ...
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the contents of the JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

You're closing the `<tr>` tag immediately, instead of After you added all the `<td>`'s to it. Try something like:

```
$.each(data.result, function(key, value){
    tableData += '<tr><td>' + key + '   ' + '</td>';
    alert(key)
    $.each(value, function(val){
        alert(value[val])
        tableData += '<td>' + value[val] + '</td>';
    });
    // Only close the <tableRow> after all the <td> elements have been added.
    tableData += '</tr>';
});
```

If the table is stil not as your desired output, please post a sample of the JSON and if you have control over this structure.

Comment: `Developer Office Koukan Jorudan Beam Software`
`Publisher Shouei VAP Hi Tech Expressions`
`ReleaseDate March 18, 1994 November 18, 1994 October 1, 1993`
`Title Idea no Hi Pachinko Hi Hisshouhou hunThe Hunt for Red October
`

Comment: Still comes out wrong I have result = `defaultdict(list)` that gets returned like `return jsonify(result=result)` which is a list object and has the exact format as the comment above

Comment: Can you post it in a formatted way, so we see the structure fo the JSON, including the brackets?